# What design for AWS Multi organization and Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-organizations

I am managing multiple accounts in AWS: each company we have as client has its own organization and they have some aws resources attached to it.

At the moment, users login with user and email using Cognito (there is a pool on our root account) and get a JWT token. One of the information in this token is the aws_access_id and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY of a user in the client account. Then, when they make a request in our api, they use this token and i can make request to the aws api.

This is a poor design since the token can be decoded easily and anyone can then get the aws credentials for their account (they are not encoded).

Now, I don't know how I could improve the flow though... Keeping Cognito would be good but protecting my tokens would be really important. What would you suggest?

EDIT: I tried using identity pools. With identity pools, you can connect with email/password with cognito and receive aws credentials that give access to a specific role. This role can then access the resources of another account. You "just" need to create one role per account. The problem I see with that is providing directly the access,secret,session to my client. Any alternative?